# Time dilation of induced dipolar gravitational fields

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

In [gravitoelectromagnetism,](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0311030) [changing gravitomagnetic fields can induce standard gravitational fields,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism) much in the same way that changing magnetic fields induce electric fields. This analogy extends to the case of [transformers;](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d436/f39ac992cb61d578ec5851c5407ffaada21d.pdf) where electricity and wires are replaced by dense fluids and pipes.

Given that the Schwarzschild metric is inapplicable in this instance, how can we calculate the gravitational time dilation due to the induced gravitational field of a dense fluid undergoing minor axis acceleration in pipes wound around a toroid, at either end of the induced dipolar field?

Comment: use the linearized approximation to GR.

Comment: Might you elaborate a little bit please? My GR skills leave much to be desired.

Comment: There's little to add: either you know this approach to weak-field GR or you do not. In a suitable coordinate choice (also known as gauge choice) the field equation becomes a wave equation with a source. This is part of any textbook introduction at say final year undergraduate or first year graduate level. If you are having a go at this without such a background then it is doable but its hard for anyone to give you the start you need. It would be some chapters of a textbook.

Comment: What is “minor axis acceleration”?

Comment: Where is the “end” of the field?

Comment: My apologies for not being more explicit. Minor axis acceleration would be acceleration around the minor axis of the toroid, around the "tube" of the toroid itself, perpendicular to the circle that the toroid makes. The "ends" of the field would be two points separated by some distance, which occupy spaces at the attractive and repulsive portions of the dipolar field respectively.